# python multiprocessing to execute a for loop in parallel

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, google-bigquery, python-multiprocessing

I have a specific requirement where I am using Big query for loop do some ETL. The for loop iterates over 35k times but it takes almost 1 minute for each iteration to complete.
I want to implement a python multiprocessing code where I will call my BQ stored procedure in python for loop and let that run parallel?

how should I achieve this?
Is this really possible to do that or there are some other ways i can run the for loop parallelly, I cannot escape the for loop.

Comment: most likely those Big Query code is executed in the cloud (async), just setup a list of async requests and wait till they are all finished, no need to use parallel processing

Comment: Can you please explain in a little bit more detail

Comment: if it is a for loop is there dependencies between the iterations, give a simple example of the kind of calculations you want to do, where do you want to parallelize on your local computer or in the cloud

Comment: I want to do the parallel operation on cloud. I have a sales product table..it has around 36k product id for which i want to run the iterations. Inside the for loop, I have various if conditions based on which i will insert the value in the column.. i am dealing with 6 columns and have more than 15-20 if conditions…those in turn call some other functions and stored procedures to assign the value to the column. It is almost 5 thousand lines of code and one iteration is taking 1 minute approximately right now..but i want this procedure to finish may be in an hour or so if not better than that

Comment: why don't you start N versions of the script, each script has parameters `scriptId` `[0..N-1]` and `N`, and only processes records with `recordId%N==scriptId`, you can create a "shell script" to spawn these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import multiprocessing
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Define your BigQuery stored procedure call function
def call_stored_procedure(iterations):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    # Your code

def main():
    num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()  # Number of CPU cores
    iterations_per_process = 1000  # Adjust this based on your workload

    # Create a pool of processes
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)

    # Submit tasks to the pool
    for _ in range(0, 35000, iterations_per_process):
        pool.apply_async(call_stored_procedure, (iterations_per_process,))

    # Close the pool and wait for all processes to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: if you don't pass the start index how does `call_stored_procedure` know where to start